# replacing text between two strings in javascript using greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

On a forum I frequent the admin recently decided to remove the bit of php code the interprets the forum code "[youtube][/youtube]" to embed youtube videos on the page. This left all these posts with these ugly broken links in them. So is what I would like to do is use greasemonkey to run some javascript code to replace the youtube tags with the code to embed the youtube video in the page iframe. The syntax for embedding the video in the page is like this

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

My issue here is I can't seem to figure out how to get the link from between the broken "[youtube]" tags and use it in the rest of my script. So for example if a post had this in it.

```
[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k[/youtube]
```

I would like to save the link between the two "[youtube]" tags to a variable.

Comment: Are you trying to edit the post, using markup, or just display the YouTube videos for your own use?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be with a regular expression.

```
var comment = "[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k[/youtube]",
    match = comment.match(/\[youtube\]([^\[]*)\[\/youtube\]/);
if (match) {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = match[1];
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```